# How to efficiently filter data from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have data in `tuple_list` and `dictionaries_list` and in both the lists there can be thousands of records.
I want to filter data from `dictionaries_list` based on records from `tuple_list`. Currently I wrote following code but it takes lot of time as for each element from list of tuples it has to iterate entire list of dictionaries.

```
# tuple_list can be like [(('s', 45), ('t', 30)), (('s', 5), ('t', 3))]
for target_tuple in tuple_list:
    # target_tuple can have data like (('s', 45), ('t', 30))
    # dictionaries_list can have data like [{'a': 5, 's': 45, 't': 10}, {}, {}]
    if some_parameter == 'something':
        m1_dicts = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d['s'] == target_tuple[0][1]]
    else:
        m1_dicts = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d['t'] == target_tuple[0][1]]
```

Please suggest some way to improve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you wanna keep the dictionary if any of the tuple_list found match within the dictionary.
It did improve a bit on runtime because it only run through tuple_list once, but might not the best optimize yet as it still need to iterate through list of dictionaries

```
# taking small dataset as example
tuple_list=[(('s', 45), ('t', 30)), (('s', 5), ('t', 6))]
dictionaries_list = [{'a': 5, 's': 45, 't': 10}, {'s':5,'t':6}, {'a':2,'s':22,'t':30}]

tuple_dict = {}
tuple_dict['s'] = [i[0][1] for i in tuple_list]
tuple_dict['t'] = [i[1][1] for i in tuple_list]
if some_parameter == 'something':
    # check for 's'
    m1_dicts = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d['s'] in tuple_dict['s']]
    # m1_dicts = [{'a': 5, 's': 45, 't': 10}, {'s':5,'t':6}]
else:
    # check for 't'
    m1_dicts = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d['t'] in tuple_dict['t']]
    # m1_dicts = [{'s':5,'t':6}, {'a':2,'s':22,'t':30}]
```

Instead of some_parameter = 'something', suggest to use some_patameter as the key to check for

```
some_parameter = 's' # check for 's'
m1_dicts = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d[some_parameter] in tuple_dict[some_parameter]]
```

Comment: This will increase memory as well as cpu consumption. you are iterating through entire list of dictionaries as well as converting members to set and intersection operation. Also you are not considering all items from tuple list.

Comment: @ShriShinde, i have revise the answer to considering all items from tuple list